# Change OpenID provider from Blogspot to Google Account

Tags: support, openid

I use my [blogspot](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/) account as my OpenID login account to log into StackOverflow ( and other openid enabled website). On a second thought, I believe that maybe using my Google account is a better idea.

Is there anyway to switch the OpenID provider and at the same time, retaining the information pertaining to that account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackOverflow has support for a second OpenID.  Go to your profile and Click *New Login*.  You can make your new login the primary OpenID by clicking *swap*.

This is site site specific.  Other websites may have their own way of doing it, or not have the ability.

Comment: I did the same. Logged in using Yahoo and did a New Login for Google. Still my yahoo rep is not reflected on the new google login.

Comment: Did you create a second account by mistake?  You'll need to contact a moderator to merge them; email team@superuser.com.