# Associating SO Account with different GMail?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid

I'm not entirely too sure on how the whole GMail accounts work, therefore any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is how to associate my current StackOverflow account with a different GMail account. I've already changed the e-mail in my 'Edit' section of profile, however I still have to login to my old e-mail in order to get into SO! Please advise! Thank you :)

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/change-openid-provider-from-blogspot-to-google-account

Comment: Not a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and after some trial and error, finally figured out how to solve it.  Here's the trick that worked for me:

1. Log into your SO account using your old GMail account (the one your SO account is currently associated to)
2. Now go into a separate Gmail window and log out of GMail (you could also just go to the Google home page and click sign out)
3. Now go back to the SO browser window, and click the "change openid" link in your profile
4. When confronted with the list of openid providers, now click "Google".
5. This will take you to a Google login page. Enter your other GMail credentials here (for the gmail account you want to associate), and log in.
6. Accept Google's notification page letting you know that you're logging into SO.
7. You'll get redirected back to SO, and it will tell you that this is an openid that SO has never seen before. Agree to this page.
8. Voilà, your SO account will be associated with your other gmail account.

The key to making this all work is step #2 above: signing out of gmail/google after you've logged into SO.  Otherwise, you'll still be logged into Google when you try to select a new OpenID, so instead of getting a Google login box, when you select Google in Step #4, you'll simply be re-logged-in to your existing Gmail account and never get an opportunity to select a new gmail account.

BTW, I suspect you can avoid these hassles by simply unchecking the "remember me" option when you associate to your google openid in the first place.

Comment: With the newer StackExchange interface, steps 3 and 4 are now: my logins --> add more logins --> [click Google icon]. Great advice: fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your user profile and click on "new login" (next to "edit"). That will let you associate a new OpenID with your account.

You can then switch which one is the "primary" ID back on the profile page - there's a "swap" link next to "Alt OpenID".

Comment: Hi Jon - your answer works if you're trying to add a non-Google openid, but if you already have a google openid associated to your gmail account, your answer didn't work for me.  I was never presented with an opportunity to log into my other google account. Instead, since I was still logged into my original google account, SO assumed I wanted to use that one again. See my answer below for a process that worked for me. In an nutshell: between logging into SO using my Google account and changing the openid in my SO profile, I had to log out (in a separate browser window) from my google account.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your profile which will take you to the page 
 http:/meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12345

Then change the url to 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12345**?tab=accounts**

This will allow you to associate to other accounts..

Comment: the question isn't about associating your Stack Overflow/Server Fault/Super User/MetaSO accounts, it's about changing the Google-provided OpenID you use to login to your SOFU accounts.